# No Add Rows Operation allowed when a DataGrid binds to a list or observable collection of Double

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, value-type

I have an `ObservableCollection<double>` that is defined in my ViewModel.

```
ListWidthsFlat=new ObservableCollection<double>();
ListWidthsFlat.Add(120);
ListWidthsFlat.Add(200);
```

My XAML code :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListWidthsFlat}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Width}" Binding="{Binding ., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

What I want is show the ObservableCollection, then offer possibility to add/delete items from my `ObservableCollection<double>`.

When I do the same thing on an `ObservableCollection<T>` all is working perfectly.
But when binding to `ObservableCollection<double>`, seems that parameters `CanUserAddRows` is not working.

**Edit** :

After additional tests, it seems the problem is that when I bind a DataGrid to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, and set `CanUserAddRow=True`, an additional empty line is automatically created (so I can edit it and add a new item to ObservableCollection.

When I bind a DataGrid to `ObservableCollection<double>`, no empty line is created.

Here is a screenshot to make it more understandable :

[image]

Comment: Where did `Items` come from? It seems you should be using `{Binding .}` (or just `{Binding}`). If that then means that you encounter a different problem, ask a question about that.

Comment: @canton7 I believed that `Items` refer to each item of my ObservableCollection (ListWidthsFlat), in that case ListWidthsFlat is a list of widths. I fillfull it in my ViewModel, then I may be able to edit it.

Comment: How is the `ListWidthsFlat` and the `Items` actually are defined in code behind? Update/edit your post with that.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan maybe I didn't understand something? Items isn't supposed to be the items in my ObservableCollection(ListWidthsFlat)? Regarding last edit from canton7, it seems I may use `Binding .`, so will edit my question regarding that

Comment: `Binding Path=Items` suggests that you are NOT binding to just `double`s.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan just edited question, thanks for precision, so when can `Binding Path=Items` be used? I don't see, as when I bind to an Item, I always say to which property I want to bind?

Comment: You can use `{Binding Path=Items}` when you have an object which has a property called `Items`. There's nothing magic about the name "Items".

Comment: @canton7 believed Items was a reserved word... well after continuing testing with `Binding .`, I see that the problem is that no "empty line" is added in my GridView, as it is done for GridViews binding on objects. Delete line is working fine. will make a printscreen so will be better understandable.

Comment: On binding, to be clear, one never references the container list indirectly such as pulling off the `Items` as your suggestion. A good rule of thumb to remember is binding is reflection **to** an object. Your datagrid binds to its `DataContext` which has a reference to an object with a property named `ListWidthsFlat` and that sets the top level binding. Within `ListsWidthsFlat` each row will bind to an individuals row to another *possibly* named object instance's property. Using `.` as binding says, just hit the object's (in the current row's) `ToString`. HTH

Comment: @ΩmegaMan not sure I understood, using `.` is not a "clean" way to bind on my doubles?May I add another `ObservableCollection<string>` in my `DataContext`, and always convert to `ObservableCollection<double>` when I modify it? In fact I Understand what you say about hitting object's `ToString`, but I don't see another way to do that? Then for your information, about your answer lower, I also found that possibility, but I think it is not really "beautiful" to make an object just to store a double. So I finally opted for another solution adding an "Add" button in these cases.

Comment: The add make the most sense in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly do a `CanUserAddRows` the object list being bound to must implement [IEditableCollectionView Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview?view=netframework-4.8) which provide basic editing capabilities to the collection being bound to. Within that the item being presented from the list has to have a public default parameterless constructor.

Because a value type `double` does not have a constructor the grid detects that and does not provide an add row; hence you see the failure on `double` alone, but it works on the object, (*class*) instances of `List<T>` which have double as a specific property.

---

To work around the limitation,

1. Create a class which has a public parameterless constructor and one `double` property.
2. Then create your list of class and bind to that `ObservableCollection` (or `List` works too actually if you don't need the overhead of the observablecollection.) with a set of your values.
3. In Xaml set the column in the datagrid to point to the double property.
4. You may need to write a value constructor which will take in a float and return a string, and convert a string to a float.